# Running R from Python

Tags: python, r

I need to run `R script` from `Python`, here are the used codes :

R code:

```
# max.R

myArgs<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
nums=as.numerics(myArgs)
cat(max(nums))
```

Python code:

```
# run_max.py

import subprocess
command="Rscript"
path2script="E:/.../codes/max.R"
args=['11','3','9','42']
cmd=[command,path2script]+args
x=subprocess.check_output(cmd,universal_newlines=True)
print x
```

When I execute the Python code, it raises an error :

```
E:\...\codes>python run_max.py
Error in as.numerics(myArgs) :
  impossible de trouver la fonction "as.numerics"
Exécution arrêtée
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_max.py", line 16, in <module>
    x=subprocess.check_output(cmd,universal_newlines=True)
  File "C:\Python2713\lib\subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['Rscript', 'E:/.../codes/max.R', '11', '3', '9', '42']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: The problem is not in `python` it is in the command `as.numerics(myArgs)` which should be `as.numeric(myArgs)`

Comment: Shame on me hahaha, thanks a lot

Comment: No worries we won't tell anyone...